# How do I dynamically create a local variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, irb

I am trying to dynamically create local variables in Ruby using `eval` and mutate the local-variables array. I am doing this in IRB.

```
eval "t = 2"
local_variables # => [:_]
eval "t"
# => NameError: undefined local variable or method `t' for main:Object
local_variables << "t".to_sym # => [:_, :t]
t
# => NameError: undefined local variable or method `t' for main:Object
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? What's the purpose?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i asked myself exactly the same question. Most probably the original problem can be solved in a much simpler way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to use the correct [binding](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Binding.html). In IRB for example this would work:

```
irb(main):001:0> eval "t=2", IRB.conf[:MAIN_CONTEXT].workspace.binding
=> 2
irb(main):002:0> local_variables
=> [:t, :_]
irb(main):003:0> eval "t"
=> 2
irb(main):004:0> t
=> 2
```

Comment: What about out of IRB? `ruby myfile.rb`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm not sure, `TOPLEVEL_BINDING` and other binding instances in ObjectSpace don't seem to work.

Answer (score 17):

You have to synchronize the evaluations with the same binding object. Otherwise, a single evaluation has its own scope.

```
b = binding
eval("t = 2", b)
eval("local_variables", b) #=> [:t, :b, :_]
eval("t", b) # => 2
b.eval('t') # => 2
```

Comment: Thanks.   How do I get the binding for main Object.   Everytime you run b = binding; it gives back a different binding object.

Comment: I was look for the outer binding to change.  Not the b binding.  When I type in t, it not part of the binding.  I have to always type in eval(dosomethingwitht,b)

Comment: @ppone: again, what are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: Please see Stefan answer.

Comment: He means why you are trying to dynamically set local variables at all. Your problem can probably be solved differently, without setting local variables dynamically and, above all, without using `eval`.

Comment: I was just curious why it was not getting set.  Your probably right there is a more efficient way to do it.  Getting an answer to this question, helps me understand Ruby somewhat better.

Comment: I still don't see an answer anywhere here as to how, in general, to dynamically create a local variable in the existing context/binding, since `binding` always creates a new context.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin `binding` does not create a new context. It refers to the current context.

Comment: So why does `eval('var=1',binding)` not create a new local variable `var`?  (I saw you're most recent answer referring to Ruby 2.1 ...)

Comment: @PeterAlfvin It does create `var`. I do not understand the relation to  another answer of mine that you mention.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I thought you were.

Comment: Anyway, in your answer to this question, `t` remains undefined in the current context (i.e. in the context the `eval` calls are being made).

Comment: @PeterAlfvin That answer is correct, but is irrelevant to my answer. It is using `eval` without passing the binding argument, which is what the OP of this question is doing.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you hadn't missed my earlier comment about `t` not being defined in the current context in your answer. :-)

Answer (score 8):

You could set instance variables like this:

```
instance_variable_set(:@a, 2)
@a
#=> 2
```

Comment: The question is not about instance variables.

Comment: That's true but maybe this could also solve the problem the OP has. As already said in my comment on the original question, i expect a much simpler solution to be feasible for the original problem.

Comment: also as an alternative method don't forget about `define_method`.