# Is there a way to do recursion with keyword arguments in ruby 2 without re-specifying each argument?

Tags: ruby, recursion, named-parameters, keyword-argument

Assume I have a method header:

```
def meth(a: val1, b: val2, c: val3)
```

and inside `meth`, I want to make a recursive call, and pass all the same arguments, but change one..

maybe something similar to this, semantically:

```
meth(_args_.merge(c: newval))
```

is this possible?

Comment: Could you make the argument a hash, merge it with a hash containing the defaults, do what you need to do in `meth`, then change the one key for the recursion?  I understand something like that was done before named parameters were supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if a built-in method exists to do so, but it's evidently possible using `local_variables` and some eval-fu:

```
def foo(bar: :baz)
  Hash[local_variables.map { |k| [k, eval("#{k}")] }]
end

foo # {:bar=>:baz}
```

Related question:

[How do I dynamically create a local variable in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842765/how-do-i-dynamically-create-a-local-variable-in-ruby)

Comment: local_variables is neat. Though, this method has quite a few non-formal arguments - so local_variables is quite big. Is there maybe a cleaner way to pass only what the method header has?
I suppose one could do `method(:meth).parameters.map{|a| a.last}` and filter `local_variables` base on the result of that. At that point, it would be about as long as specifying all the parameters. lol. Still neat to know that this is possible though.

Comment: Null, if you did that, you might use `method(__method__).parameters...` instead.