# Unable to assign instance_variable_get values to dynamic variable in ruby

Tags: ruby

Instance_variable_get value can be assigned to a variable as follows. The following code throws correct output

```
a = instance_variable_get("@" + "#{code}" + "_resource").get_price(a, b) // working
```

But unable to assign instance_variable_get value to a variable with dynamic param. Assume the code is a dynamic param which is in loop.

```
"#{code}_buy" = instance_variable_get("@" + "#{code}" + "_resource").get_price(a, b) //Not working
```

The above method throws the following error

```
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
```

Comment: It's basically impossible to set local variable dynamically.

Comment: @MarekLipka - How can I intelligently change my code?

Comment: imposible set to string value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842765/how-do-i-dynamically-create-a-local-variable-in-ruby

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash instead:

```
hash = {}
hash["#{code}_buy"] = some_value
```